# images hosted in imgur.com

Tags: support

I have imgur blocked at work, I've written a script that scrapes the image from imgur, if your isp/work has it blocked; now is there a way i can implement it in gis.stackexchange so I don't have to look through the source?

**EDIT**

or at least have the css so a box is shown and when you right click it, can get the link. What currently happens is that there is no way to tell if there is an image in an answer unless I check the source code

Answer (score 4):

fimnot is an Imagur mirror.

If you install the following greasemonkey script, the imgur links in the page you are seeing will be automatically replaced by the corresponding fimnot link:

http://filmot.com/imgur_filmot.user.js

Hence I don't really see why we should replace the image hosting site. If you replace it by soem other site, tomorrow that site may be blocked. The only solution is if the images are hosted at Stackexchange.com; And I don't think that is going to happen.

Comment: Your script only works on reddit, and only for anchors (not for img tags)... You can find an updated version [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83256/my-link-not-visible-to-me/83275#83275).

Answer (score 3):

One thing to try is the [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) add-on for Firefox. On the shared script site, [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org), there are [a few mentioning imgur.com](http://userscripts.org/scripts/search?q=imgur.com&x=11&y=7) which could be used as starting points. Oh, that's interesting, one of the scripts there, *reddit imgur unblocker*,  is missing, but it's description mentions a mirror: [filmot.com](http://filmot.com). Maybe all you need to do write a simple search and replace script?

It's also probably worthwhile asking central IT why they're blocking imgur.com; maybe you can get the rule relaxed for you.